# How to control .cache folder location?

Tags: vimrc

Is there an option to control .cache folder location in Vim? Is there a setting or a variable for this?

Comment: Are you using Vim or Neovim?

Comment: For what is Vim using that location; I'm not aware that it's used?! In general, the `XDG_CACHE_HOME` environment variable controls this.

Comment: I am using Vim.

Comment: It seems like XDG_CACHE_HOME env var works. Do you know if there is a way to do it via .vimrc?

Comment: You can try `:let $XDG_CACHE_HOME = '...'` in your `~/.vimrc`. I'm still curious what kind of files Vim is placing there (and which you want moved elsewhere)?

Comment: @IngoKarkat my money’s on a plugin or janus-like setup

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the differences between Vim and Neovim. The latter supports XDG, the former doesn't. That being said, you can make Vim to respect XDG by manually setting some locations, but you have to decide what kind of stuff you want to put on `$XDG_CONFIG_CACHE`. For example you could put your `.viminfo` there: `set viminfo+=n$XDG_CACHE_HOME/vim/viminfo`. Also backups and swap files:

```
set directory=$XDG_CACHE_HOME/vim
set backupdir=$XDG_CACHE_HOME/vim
```

(Neovim consider these data, so they go in `$XDG_DATA_HOME` instead).

As a side note, to have all your configuration on `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` you can use

```
set runtimepath=$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/vim,$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/vim/after,$VIM,$VIMRUNTIME
let $MYVIMRC="$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/vim/vimrc"
```